# Remove objects from previous array if they don't match the new one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove the values that don't match in the previous array to the values in the new array.

```
var previous = [
    {m: "195/50 15"},
    {m: "195/50 16"},
    {m: "195/55 15"},
    {m: "195/55 16"},
    {m: "195/55 20"}
];
var newOne = [
    {m: "195/55 15"},
    {m: "195/55 16"},
    {m: "195/55 20"}
];

console.log( previous.filter((obj) => obj['m'] !== newOne['m']) );
```

And if the new array is empty, then the filter should return an empty array.

The method I am trying above doesn't work.

Comment: What should be the desired output here?

Comment: @talentedandrew The new array.

Comment: Your comparing the array item with the object here. Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using some to determine if the value is in the other array:

```js
var previous = [
    {m: "195/50 15"},
    {m: "195/50 16"},
    {m: "195/55 15"},
    {m: "195/55 16"},
    {m: "195/55 20"}
];
var newOne = [
    {m: "195/55 15"},
    {m: "195/55 16"},
    {m: "195/55 20"}
];

const result = previous.filter(p => {
  return newOne.some(n => n.m === p.m);
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison should be like this

```js
var previous = [
    {m: "195/50 15"},
    {m: "195/50 16"},
    {m: "195/55 15"},
    {m: "195/55 16"},
    {m: "195/55 20"}
];
var newOne = [
    {m: "195/55 15"},
    {m: "195/55 16"},
    {m: "195/55 20"}
];

console.log( previous.filter((obj, i) => newOne[i] && obj['m'] !== newOne[i]['m']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using filter function that runs through objects inside previous array and compares each object value with newOne['m'] which returns `undefined`

```
    let newArray = []

    previous.forEach(pobj => {
      newOne.forEach(nobj => {
        if(pobj['m'] === nobj['m']){
          newArray.push(pobj)
        }
      })
    })

    console.log(newArray)
```